# Does ejabberd community edition support rest API

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I can't find clear information about the differences between Ejabberd Business and Ejabberd community (apart from the list of RFC/XEP here : https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/).

Especially about the rest API : does community edition support it ?
In the documentation (https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/) there is no info about which functionnality is supported by which version.

I also found this page : https://feedback.process-one.net/support/solutions/folders/6000076557 on the Business edition features but it seems to be outdated.

Thank you for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you enable mod_http_api, it provides ReST API in JSON format. Alternatively, if you install mod_rest from ejabberd-contrib git repository, you can execute commands with HTTP POST queries.